# Two mouseenter functions operating at once? (animate color and play sound)

Tags: jquery, audio, jquery-animate, mouseenter

I've been using the cloned audio script on [this website](https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/) to get audio to play on mouseenter.

```
    $(".wrapper")
  .each(function(i) {
    if (i != 0) {
      $("#beep-two")
        .clone()
        .attr("id", "beep-two" + i)
        .appendTo($(this).parent());
    }
    $(this).data("beeper", i);
  })
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $("#beep-two" + $(this).data("beeper"))[0].play();
  });
$("#beep-two").attr("id", "beep-two0");
```

I've also been implementing a mouseenter function with a color animation. My code for that is on [JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fz39N/476/)

I can get the color and the sound to function independently. But neither will work when I use them at once.

How do I make a color animation and sound both play on mouseenter of each word of my code?

Comment: could you update the fiddle with the exact code including audio ?

Comment: Thanks! With both codes: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz39N/481/)
Nothing seems to function when I do this. I'm very new to jQuery, so I may be making a big error.